# Links in list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, links

I have a list of tables in my dissertation formatted like this:

[image]

Is there a way to make the "Table 2.1" and the page number, but not the caption text or the dots link to the table?

I know `\hypersetup` can be used to either make everything except for the dots link with `linktoc=all`, or make just the page number link with `linktoc=page`. `hyperref` doesn't seem to directly offer finer control.

Comment: What's the reason for the request? If you make (for example) the link invisible then there is maybe no need for that.

Comment: The reason is that I find that behavior intuitive. I can easily imagine someone hovering over "Table 2.1" and seeing that it doesn't have a link not checking the page number and getting frustrated that there aren't any links even though there are. I don't want the text to be a link because I have citations in the captions.

Comment: Don't put citations in the LoT entries. `\caption[LoT entry]{Body entry with citations}`